# Hibernate:can't fetch data from related one-to-one tables

Tags: hibernate, mapping, fetch, one-to-one, subquery

There are `User`,`Person` and `Employee` entities.
`User` knows about both `Person` and `Employee`.

hibernate config for User:

```
...
<many-to-one name="person" class="entry.Person" column="perid" not-null="true" cascade="all"/>
<many-to-one name="employee" class="entry.Employee" column="empid" not-null="true" cascade="all"/>
...
```

DAO:

```
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from User");
}
```

When fetch users with `getUsers()`,that `Person` and `Employee` data is `NULL`.

Have I missed some `.hbm` configuration or I should manually add more subselects to `DAO`?

**EDIT**
context:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>
...
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="dao.UserDaoHibernate">
        <property name="factory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

dao:

```
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<User> getUsers() {      

        Session s = this.factory.getCurrentSession();
...
```

got `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`,when try to execute `getCurrentSession()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, associations in Hibernate are lazy fetched unless otherwise specified in your Hibernate configuration, or initialized in code.  Eager fetching in configuration is not encouraged, to avoid unexpected consequences.  In your code above, you will need to explicitly initialize the `Person` and `Employee` associations.

Since you are using Spring, for coding ease you should stop using the `HibernateTemplate` ([which hasn't been recommended to use for a while](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/)), and move over to using Hibernate directly.  Then, you can use `Hibernate.initialize` on the associations (or some other method, like setting `FetchMode`) to initialize them.

Comment: Thank you for hint.As I understand,it's recommended to do such a migration:`getHibernateTemplate().update(user)` change to `factory.openSession().saveOrUpdate(user)` ?Unfortunately got `Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions` wne execute `factory.openSession().saveOrUpdate(user)`

Comment: Your DAO should `@Autowire` the Hibernate `SessionFactory`, and then you make calls to `getCurrentSession()`.  See: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight.

Comment: Could you,please,see EDIT section in my post.Tried to do as in reference you advised,but got exception.`@Transactional` is specified for DAO methods.

Comment: Right, because Hibernate needs to be run inside of a Transaction.  `getHibernateTemplate` does that internally, so migrating to raw Hibernate means you need to add Transaction configuration to your Spring config.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations